# Which TFS Permissions Need to be Denied to Prevent a Branch Appearing in the "Merge" Dialog?

Tags: tfs, version-control

Our TFS processes used to use a branch-per-revision technique. Although I've changed that now, we still have old branches from the "per release" days.

When I start a "Merge" from our "DEV" (main, trunk) branch, I still see all of the old release branches as possible merge targets. This is inconvenient.

Short of deleting the old branches, is there a set of permissions I can apply which will keep everyone (including me) from seeing those branches in the "Merge" dialog as targets?

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **deny read** permissions on those branches in source control. After doing this, the branch will be shielded in TFS. You can do this in the VS(right click the branch-advanced-security) or using [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command)

However in your situation, I will recommend you to delete the branch, since you want to applicable to **everybody**. Delete is the simplest solution, and you can undelete it if needed. Setting permissions are works well when preventing **someone** to access the source contorl folder. But not the best one in this case.